# How to handle redirection with force:createRecord

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

I am working with Lightning Experience. I have used force:createRecord for creating new record, and everything work fine unless the redirection after Save button clicked. (it's redirected to the record page while I hope I could make it stay and only refresh current page).

Could you guy please tell me how to refresh current page after click Save button?

P/s: Save button is a button of a page (look like dialog) when force:createRecord event called

Comment: Just wondering is there any update on this? I'm having a similar issue. I want to redirect to a custom component after a record is created but can't figure out how to override being redirected to the record page. Any help much appreciated...

Comment: Hi @pduffy44, I didn't find out solution for that (override save button in force.createRecord), so I've solved my issue with the other solution. In stead of using force:createRecord, I made my own dialog (this could take time for lookup fields, validation ...) but this is the only way I could go at that time. Hope this help.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/223283/override-e-forcecreaterecord-default-behaviour-on-save. one post here did the trick, I have tried and it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the standard designed behavior of force:create record. There is no way to handle the redirection on click of Save button. If you want to do that you have to prepare a custom component for that.

Comment: There is a post here did a trick: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/223283/override-e-forcecreaterecord-default-behaviour-on-save

Answer (score 4):

There is an undocumented solution for this. Below is the js controller function that creates a new Contact record and redirects back from the record page to the initial page after a new record is created.

```
createNewContact: function(component, event, helper) {
    var windowHash = window.location.hash;
    var createEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
    createEvent.setParams({
        "entityApiName": "Contact",
        "panelOnDestroyCallback": function(event) {
            window.location.hash = windowHash;
        }
    });
    createEvent.fire();
}
```

Where "panelOnDestroyCallback" is the hidden force:createRecord attribute.
I know that's an ugly hack, but hey, if I had known this before I wouldn't have spent 50+ hours implementing a fully-custom multi-object 'createRecord' component with all the schema tricks, custom lookups, multipicklists etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to refresh the whole page. So I used -

window.location.href = window.location.href;

instead of 
window.location.hash = windowHash;

It did the trick.