# How do I check and wait on the results of force:createRecord

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a component showing case notes with a simple toggle button for public/private. I'm trying to use a popup for creating a new case note. It also works fine but how do I wait on the results before I requery and redraw the associated case notes? I click new comment, it pops up the new dialog box, I fill in the comment and click save. The comment is properly added but the list of case comments is queried before the new comment is inserted into the database

cmp

```
<aura:component controller="mevLCaseComment" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
  <aura:attribute name="commentList" type="casecomment[]" />
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />   
  <article class="slds-card slds-card_boundary related_list_card_border_top forceRelatedListCardDesktop" >
    <div class="container forceRelatedListSingleContainer" style="padding: 5px 5px">

        <lightning:icon iconName="custom:custom19" alternativeText="Case Notes"/><lightning:formattedText value=" - Case Comments" /> 
         <div class="slds-float_right"> <button style="align:right;width:75px !important;" class="slds-button slds-button--icon-border" onclick="{!c.createRecord}" label="New Comment">New Comment</button>        </div>
      <div style="width:100%"><hr></hr></div>
      <table>
        <tr><th style="width: 20%">Created By</th><th style="width: 20%">Date/Time</th><th style="width: 50%">Comment</th><th>Public</th></tr>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.commentList}" var="cc" >
          <tr>
            <td>{!cc.CreatedBy.Name}</td>
            <td><ui:outputDateTime value="{!cc.CreatedDate}" format="M/D/YYYY HH:mm a"/></td>
            <td>{!cc.CommentBody}</td>
            <td>&nbsp;<ui:outputCheckbox aura:id="outputBox" value="{!cc.IsPublished}"/></td>
            <td>
              <aura:if isTrue="{!cc.IsPublished}">
                <button data-id="{!cc.Id}" style="width:50px !important" class="slds-button slds-button--icon-border" label="Make Private" onclick="{!c.makePrivate}">Make Private</button>
                <aura:set attribute="else">
                  <button data-id="{!cc.Id}" style="width:50px !important" class="slds-button slds-button--icon-border" label="Make Public" onclick="{!c.makePublic}">Make Public</button>
                </aura:set>                  
              </aura:if>  
            </td>  
          </tr>
          <tr class="ccdividerrow"><td colspan="5"><hr></hr></td></tr>
        </aura:iteration>
      </table>    
    </div>
  </article>
</aura:component>
```

.js

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.apexCall(component, event, helper, 'getCaseComments', component.get('v.recordId'));
    },
    makePublic: function(component, event, helper) {
        var ccid = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        helper.apexCall(component, event, helper, 'changeToPublic', ccid);
    },
    makePrivate: function(component, event, helper) {
        var ccid = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        helper.apexCall(component, event, helper, 'changeToPrivate', ccid);
    },
    createRecord: function(component,event,helper) {
      var ccid = component.get('v.recordId');
        console.log('Retrieved ParentId: ' + ccid);
      var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");      
      createRecordEvent.setParams({
          "entityApiName": "CaseComment","defaultFieldValues": { "ParentId" : ccid }
      });
      createRecordEvent.fire();
       console.log('create Record Event has been fired');
      helper.apexCall(component, event, helper, 'getCaseComments', ccid);        
    }

})
```

helper

```
({
    apexCall: function(component, event, helper, actionName, ccid) {
        var action = component.get('c.'+actionName);
        action.setParams({ ccid: ccid });
        action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
            var state = data.getState();
            if (state === 'SUCCESS') {
                component.set('v.commentList', data.getReturnValue());
            } else {
                console.error("ERROR");
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

apex class

```
public class mevLCaseComment {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static list<casecomment> getCaseComments(id ccid) {
        system.debug(logginglevel.info, 'MEVION DEBUG: case id ' + ccid);
        return [Select Id, commentbody,ispublished,createdby.name,createddate From casecomment Where parentid = :ccid order by createddate desc]; 
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static list<casecomment> changeToPublic(string ccid) {
        system.debug(logginglevel.info, 'MEVION DEBUG: casecomment id ' + ccid);
        casecomment[] cc = [select id, parentid, ispublished from casecomment where id=:ccid];
        id pid=null;
        if(cc.size()>0) {
          cc[0].ispublished = true;
          pid = cc[0].parentid;
          update cc;
        }
        return getCaseComments(pid);
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static list<casecomment> changeToPrivate(string ccid) {
        system.debug(logginglevel.info, 'MEVION DEBUG: casecomment id ' + ccid); 
        casecomment[] cc = [select id, parentid, ispublished from casecomment where id=:ccid];
        id pid = null;
        if(cc.size()>0) {
          cc[0].ispublished = false;
          pid = cc[0].parentid;
          update cc;
        }
        return getCaseComments(pid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this?: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/203537/59064

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an event for toast and then use the toast message to write some javascript logic.

```
cmp
<aura:handler event="force:showToast" action="{!c.handleToastEvent}"/>

controller
handleToastEvent : function(component, event, helper) {
var toastMessageParams = event.getParams();
var message = toastMessageParams.message;


//if the toast includes Account (obj) and includes 'was created'
if (message.includes('Account') && message.includes('was created')) {
    //do something here such as reload after record was created.   
    $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
}else if(message.includes('Account') && message.includes('was saved')){
    //do something here such as reload after record was saved.
    $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
}


},
```

Comment: Thanks ebar. Was able to use detection of the Toast message to fire the getCaseComments after record was created

Answer (score 1):

`force:createRecord` does not have a callback.

Since you are using `CaseComment`, you have a very simple workaround. Just implement `recordEditForm` and create record. Then you can have handle all events like `success` and `error`. Also you can prepolute the values if needed. You can implement this form in `modal`.

Comment: Doesn't work as now I get this when I assign the record and use lighting:recordEditForm of lilghtning:recordForm   'Object CaseComment is not supported in UI API INVALID_TYPE

Comment: Sry, forgot to check that. will check for better solution and let you know.